# Does multi-file unified diff requires Index: lines?

Tags: diff

When creating a `multi-file` unified diff is `Index` line required like in the following example?

```
Index: /file1
--- /file1
+++ /file1
_changes in file 1_
Index: /file2
--- /file2
+++ /file2
_changes in file 2_
```

And what is the purpose of this `Index` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program `patch` man page tells that:

> If there is an Index: line in the leading garbage and if either the old and new names are both absent or if patch is conforming to POSIX , patch takes the name in the Index: line.

I believe it's more a "old" thing used for the legacy patch format, and the patch generator that you use still generates that (in contextual and unified format the `+++/---/***` lines already do that job). It does not harm.

Comment: Thanks, but then I don't understand why is eclipse "Apply patch" requiring it? Because it wants to conform to the POSIX?

Comment: The POSIX man page (http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1/patch/), indicates that it is optional (see EXTENDED DESCRIPTION, Name determination, `If the header information contains a line beginning with the string Index:`). The eclipse team must have read the documentation a bit too fast or required it for simplicity (that way they don't have to test for patch format first nor have to try the step 1. and 2. of POSIX Name determination).